# Is there a way to host the c# code editor in a visual studio extension window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, code-editor

I'm working on a visual studio 2010 extension and was wondering on how to obtain an existing language service ( the one for C# specifically ). All the articles I've seen on the web so far are about "Implementing your own language service", but I haven't been able to find any info on obtaining an M<*existing* one.

Just to provide some context here, the extension needs to open a custom wpf form on demand,in which i want to host a C# code editor window.

I'm not yet sure this is even possible, however any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Prob doesnt help you but http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/ is what a lot of projects use in this case.

Comment: Not exactly on point, but the scintilla.net does look interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it took me forever to word this question correctly, but I found a blog post answering the question on Google: [Hosting the C# Code Editor in a Tool Window](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2010/07/28/LearnVSXNow_2D00_Part45.aspx)

I know it's kind of rude to just dump a link, but helpful nonetheless I hope.

Comment: +1 The article itself is not specific to the C# code editor, but there is a comment below the article that describes setting the editor to work specifically with C# code.

Comment: Original link is broken, however archive.org had it...
https://web.archive.org/web/20180728113200/http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2010/07/28/LearnVSXNow_2D00_Part45.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can have a look at is the [Roslyn CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27746). I've seen a demo of it at the Dutch Tech Days last week and it looks quite nice.

It can help you in hosting your own coding environment and easily compile snippets. But it's still really beta and it doesn't support all the language features yet.